# Why goroutine cannot read the global var ops value?

Tags: go, goroutine

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"
import (
    "runtime"
    "sync/atomic"
)

func init() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
}

func main() {
    var t1 = time.Now()
    var ops uint64 = 0
    go func() {
        for {
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
            opsFinal := atomic.LoadUint64(&ops)
            fmt.Println("ops:", opsFinal, "qps:", opsFinal/uint64(time.Since(t1).Seconds()))
        }
    }()

    for {
        atomic.AddUint64(&ops, 1)
        //runtime.Gosched()
    }
}
```

In this case out put "ops: 0 qps: 0" every second, why canot read ops in goroutine ?

but when add **runtime.Gosched()**, everything is ok!

Can every body help me?

Comment: Can't reproduce on Darwin 10.9.5 Go version devel. Works as expected on my machine. To say order of evaluation of concurrent goroutines without explicit sync undefined. So behavior of your code can be unpredictable which not treated as error.

Comment: my go version is 1.8

Comment: You need at least Go version go1.8.1. What is your output from the `go version` command?

Comment: @peterSO I update go version to 1.9.2，it's ok now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My read of [The Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem) is that this is a correct execution of the program you've written: nothing guarantees that the `AddUint64()` calls in the main program *happen before* the `LoadUint64()` calls in the goroutine, so it's legitimate for every read of the variable to happen before any write occurs.  I wouldn't be totally shocked if the compiler knew about `"sync/atomic"` as special and concluded that the result of the increment was unobservable, so just deleted the final loop.

Both [The Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem) and the [sync/atomic documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic) recommend against the approach you're using.  `"sync/atomic"` admonishes:

> Share memory by communicating; don't communicate by sharing memory.

A better program might look like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func count(op <-chan struct{}) {
    t1 := time.Now()
    ops := 0
    tick := time.Tick(time.Second)
    for {
        select {
        case <-op:
            ops++
        case <-tick:
            dt := time.Since(t1).Seconds()
            fmt.Printf("ops: %d qps: %f\n", ops, float64(ops)/dt)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    op := make(chan struct{})
    go count(op)
    for {
        op <- struct{}{}
    }
}
```

Note that no state is shared between the main program and the goroutine, except the data that is sent across the channel.

Comment: thanks ! Share memory by communicating; don't communicate by sharing memory

Answer (score 2):

I d update the go version, please check,

```
[mh-cbon@pc3 y] $ go run main.go 
ops: 97465383 qps: 97465383
ops: 195722110 qps: 97861055
ops: 293058057 qps: 97686019
ops: 390971243 qps: 97742810
^Csignal: interrupt
[mh-cbon@pc3 y] $ go version
go version go1.10 linux/amd64
[mh-cbon@pc3 y] $ gvm use 1.8
Now using version go1.8
[mh-cbon@pc3 y] $ go version
go version go1.8 linux/amd64
[mh-cbon@pc3 y] $ go run main.go 
ops: 0 qps: 0
ops: 0 qps: 0
^Csignal: interrupt
[mh-cbon@pc3 y] $
```